# Unity Instantiate an object with hise relative addListener

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an object dinamically with his AddListener but i can't find the right syntax

```
GameObject cube = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, x, y), Quaternion.identity, transform);
cube.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text = "Text Mesh Pro"                    
cube.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.onClick.AddListener(() => DoSomething("example"));
```

Thanks

Comment: [OnClick](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) belongs to [Buttons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) so your instatiated object needs to be a UI element and have a Button component on it. If you want to detect clicks on a 3d object then look into [Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

Answer (score 0):

What @Çağatay already mentioned. `OnClick` is part of the `UI.Unity.Button` therefore you need to get the component for that (and add it to the GameObject if not done already).

The code then would look like that:

```
cube.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => DoSomething("example")));
```